# Using OpenPop how do i save downloaded emails in message format and also attachments to the hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Maybe when downloading all emails to create one big file on hard disk of all emails and when running the program over again to parse emails ? Or to save each email to his own message file and make a specific directory for attachments ?

What i want to do is that once i downloaded all emails from server next time i will run my program i will see all the emails without the need to download them over again and if i click a button or using a timer it will download only new emails from the server next time.

This is how i'm downloading the emails today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenPop;
using OpenPop.Pop3;
using OpenPop.Mime;

namespace Pop3_Emails
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client cc = new Pop3Client();
        ProgressBarWithText pbt = new ProgressBarWithText();
        List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allMessages;
        ListViewNF lvnf;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewNF();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(250, 18);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(474, 168);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);

            label8.Visible = false;
            pbt.Size = new Size(216, 10);
            pbt.Location = new Point(8, 312);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(pbt);

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            pbt.Text = "0%";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private int numberofallmessages = 0;
        private int countMsg = 0;

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
            PopClient.Connect("mail", 110, false);
            PopClient.Authenticate("me", "me",
                OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

            int messageCount = PopClient.GetMessageCount();
            numberofallmessages = messageCount;
            allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
                int nProgress = (messageCount - i + 1) * 100 / messageCount;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
            }
            PopClient.Disconnect();        
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt.Invalidate();
            label8.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            label8.Visible = true;
            lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.From.ToString(),         //From Column
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject,                 //Subject Column
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent.ToString()      //Date Column
            }));

            countMsg += 1;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (closingForm)
                this.Close();
            label8.Text = numberofallmessages.ToString() + "/" + "0";
        }

        public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
        {
            const int WmPaint = 15;
            SizeF TextSize;
            PointF TextPos;
            bool dontpaint = false;

            public ProgressBarWithText()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
                this.TextChanged += ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged;
                this.SizeChanged += ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged;
            }

            public override string Text
            {
                get { return base.Text; }
                set { base.Text = value; }
            }

            void RecalcTextPos()
            {
                if (this.IsDisposed == true)
                    return;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
                    return;

                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
                {
                    TextSize = graphics.MeasureString(base.Text, this.Font);
                    TextPos.X = (this.Width / 2) - (TextSize.Width / 2);
                    TextPos.Y = (this.Height / 2) - (TextSize.Height / 2);
                }
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if (dontpaint == false)
                {
                    switch (m.Msg)
                    {
                        case WmPaint:
                            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                                graphics.DrawString(base.Text, base.Font, Brushes.Black, TextPos.X, TextPos.Y);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                    result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool closingForm = false;
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!closingForm && MessageBox.Show("You sure?", "Form1", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                closingForm = true;
                if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        class ListViewNF : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewNF()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that now i'm adding the emails parts to ListView control and also adding the messages to the List allMessages. But i never save the emails and attachments to the hard disk so each time i will run my program over again it will download all the emails again over 7000 emails.

Comment: Found how to do it using the exmaple in here http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSaveLoadMessage.php